# 3 year old Minpin struggling to become fully potty trained

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I have had my 3 year old Minpin for about 4-5 months now and I'm struggling to fully potty train him. He was supposedly a neglected/abused dog prior, and while I have him mostly potty trained, he has had occasional accidents, and it is starting to become more often now.

First, in general, he doesn't have many accidents. Maybe one every 2-3 weeks or so from what I have noticed. Generally speaking, he doesn't poop or pee in the house, and as long as I am home he will come and get me and whine to let me know he needs out. He will also go on command quite easily, and consistently. There are no problems here.

From time to time however, specifically when I leave for a few minutes or more, and not all the time, he will poop in the house nearly as soon as I leave. And always in the same spot. From what I have gathered, I think this is due to separation anxiety. He will whine and howl a bit while I'm gone (this has stopped now), and be super excited when I come back (jumps up and down, jumps on me, just over-the-top excitement, still happening). What is important here is that he never pees, but only poops. I am working on this and he seems to be getting a lot better. I am keeping my return home low key until he calms down, and these accidents are getting less often.

Recently however, I have gone to speak at a conference for a few days and my girlfriend watched him at her house (he was kept in the bathroom while she was at work, and he had no accidents). Now that I am back home, he has had accidents almost every other day, which has moved to both poop and pee. He peed in the living room, which I'm not sure how I missed, but I did, so I cleaned it up and moved on. This must have happened while I was at work and when I came home I missed it, but I had been home during lunch as well to let him out. His schedule has not changed at all. I had also left one evening to run an errand and he pooped (in the same spot he always does, if he does poop).

More recently, just last night, he jumped off the bed and wet in my room on the floor, but he did not let me know he had to go like he generally does. Generally he will get off the bed, whine to wake me up or lick me face or hand, and I will get up to let him out. For the most part, he has not peed at all in the house for over 4 months until just recently, so his potty behavior is progressively getting worse again.

As far as training, here is what I am doing.

1. Get up and let him out to potty
2. Feed him breakfast (7:30-8:30am)
3. Let him out again before I go to work
4. Let him out again during my lunch hour
5. Let him out as soon as I get home from work
6. Feed him dinner (4:30pm consistently)
7. Let him out 2-3 more times until bed time, and just before bed

I am using positive reinforcement. I go out with him to potty, and will go pee or poop on command consistently and I treat him and praise him quite a bit. When he has a accident indoors I just clean it up and take him out. I recently have been giving him full access to the house instead of just my room because he had been doing so well without accidents.

When he was having accidents in the house at first I was putting him in the bathroom while gone at work. He never had a accident there. I then let him have access to my room, and he went a few months with no accidents except for a day he was sick and had diarrhea, so I then let him have full access to the house, where he also didn't have any accidents for a few weeks until this started again.

His potty behavior is extremely inconsistent. Some other notes.

1. He used to get up multiple times a night (excessive), sometimes 6 times to want to out potty outside. Sometimes a few times in an hour. This has stopped and for the most part he has made it through the entire night consistently for a couple months now
2. He had never peed in the house until just recently, only ever had poop accidents. I have also been letting my girlfriends dog stay as well (she stays the night), but the dogs have known each other since day one and get along really well, and my girlfriends dog does not have potty issues like my dog.
3. He sometimes will not eat his breakfast. I have to coax him with a treat and sit there and really work at it to get him to eat it. According to the many people I have talked to, and pet feeding guidelines, he's getting the right amount of food per day.
4. He apparently was mostly an outside dog. From what I understand his previous owner would scream at him all the time and toss him outside quite a bit. I think he was probably mostly an outside dog and probably not fully house trained.

I really need some help because I'm unsure how to proceed. I've read pet magazines, countless people's stories, and have been really consistent. The only thing I have not tried is crate training.

I want to be able to give him full access to the house and not lock him in the bathroom while I'm gone, and apparently now during the night, but I don't know what else to do.

Comment: Can I suggest as a first step, that you record his behaviour during the day while you are out?  If the problem is separation anxiety rather than toilet training as such, then there will probably be other clues in his behaviour that you could pick up from a webcam or something. 
I am wondering if he has regressed because he'd bonded with you and then you had to leave him for a bit, and it's a matter of rebuilding that bond.

Comment: I have a nest cam that watches him, but I've been unable to catch him in the act however. He will lay on my bed all day, and will get up and walk around for a about one minute, then poop in the same spot, and then run back into the bedroom on the bed to lay down. He doesn't exhibit any other signs, or have any other odd behaviors. He is generally very relaxed and quiet. He just gets up, looks around for a minute, then does his business. Sometimes there is a slight whine like no one is there to let him out, but not often. This behavior has been consistent.